# Apple developer account renewal -devices didn't reset

Tags: ios, iphone

I have renewed my developer account but devices didn't get reset. I have disabled all the devices, deleted all the provisional App IDs and deleted all the provisional profiles. But didn't revoke one developer certificate alone. My account is expires on 10th April 2014. But I have renewed, paid and activated the account. Now in my account details it shows the expire date as 10th April 2015. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Apple says about account renewals

> How do I reset the devices I have registered for testing and Ad Hoc
>   distribution?
>
> When Team Agents or Admins first sign in to the Certificates,
>   Identifiers & Profiles at the start of a new membership year, they
>   will be presented with the option to remove devices and restore the
>   device count for those removed devices.
>
> Removing devices during your membership year will not open these slots
>   to add new devices.
>
> Important Note: At the start of your membership year, make sure to
>   remove all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding
>   any new devices.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html

So you will have to wait until the start of your next developer year. And make sure the devices are removed at that point. You will get a option to reset the count by that time.

Comment: My exp date of account is 14-Nov-14, so delete option will show at 15-Nov-14 or should display on same date, please guide me. Thanks